Jenkins- Getting stuck at the "Getting Started" page
"Getting Started" page
Hi there! I've got a little problem I'd like some help with. I recently installed Jenkins-LTS and created pipelines etc. After a few days, I restarted the Jenkins service and found myself back at the Getting Started page. This time, the initialAdminPassword file wasn't in the last location, and now I can't open the main page.
I was able to reboot my Mac to skip this page, but it's annoying too much. it happens too often and I'm unable to trigger my pipelines.

I think you should be able to view the logs and see why it is stuck on the Getting Started page. Viewing logs in Jenkins

There is not even a log file in this location "cat: /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log: No such file or directory". I didn't customized this file "org.jenkins-ci.plist"

Did you setup it as a Docker container?

No, I installed it using HomeBrew

Well, since we don't have access to the log files. I would suggest try to setup it as a Docker container and see if the same behavior persist with a extra layer of container. Maybe it is related to some automated task in your MacOS.
